# PL/SQL - How to return variables as cursor?

Tags: variables, stored-procedures, plsql

I have some variables acquired from a stored function. I want to return them as a cursor in a stored procedure. (The reason is because I want to use them in a Jasper report and Jasper only allows stored procedures with cursor output)

My PL/SQL code is:

```
procedure myprocedure (my_cursor OUT sys_refcursor) is
    output1 TABLE1.FIELD1%TYPE;
    output2 TABLE1.FIELD2%TYPE;
    output3 TABLE2.FIELD1%TYPE;
    output4 TABLE1.FIELD3%TYPE;
    begin
        IF NOT(package1.function1 (output1, output2, output3, output3))
        THEN                
            output1 := NULL;
            output2 := NULL;
            output3 := NULL;
            output4 := NULL;
        END IF;
    open my_cursor for
    select :output1 as myoutput1, :output2 as myoutput2, :output3 as myoutput3, :output4 as myoutput4
    from DUAL
end myprocedure;
```

I get `PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'output1'`

How can I return the results of the function in a cursor?

Comment: There is no need to use colon(:) for the vriables. `select output1 as myoutput1, output2 ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving the colon(:) out as @Ramblin' Man commented solved the problem for me.

```
select output1 as myoutput1, output2 as myoutput2, output3 as myoutput3, output4 as myoutput4 from DUAL
```

The colon in SQL is called [Bind Variable](http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_bind_variables.html).

As you can see in this article, **PL/SQL itself takes care of most of the issues to do with bind variables**

Also at the end of the PL/SQL example: Now you might be thinking that you've got to replace the p_empno with a bind variable. However, the good news is that **every reference to a PL/SQL variable is in fact a bind variable**.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TABLE test_tbl
(
    col1 VARCHAR(5)
,   col2 VARCHAR(5)
,   col3 VARCHAR(5)
);


DECLARE
    l_output1 test_tbl.col1%TYPE;
    l_output2 test_tbl.col2%TYPE;
    l_output3 test_tbl.col3%TYPE;

    l_select VARCHAR2(32767);
    l_cur    SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    l_output1 := 'col1';
    l_output2 := 'col2';
  --l_output3

    l_select := 'SELECT '
                    || CASE WHEN l_output1 IS NOT NULL THEN '''' || l_output1 || ''' AS my_' || l_output1 ELSE 'NULL' END || CASE WHEN l_output2 IS NOT NULL THEN  ', ' ELSE NULL END
                    || CASE WHEN l_output2 IS NOT NULL THEN '''' || l_output2 || ''' AS my_' || l_output2 ELSE NULL   END || CASE WHEN l_output3 IS NOT NULL THEN  ', ' ELSE NULL END
                    || CASE WHEN l_output3 IS NOT NULL THEN '''' || l_output3 || ''' AS my_' || l_output3 ELSE NULL   END ||
                ' FROM DUAL';

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_select);

    OPEN l_cur FOR l_select;

    IF l_cur%ISOPEN THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('l_cur IS OPEN');

        CLOSE l_cur;
    END IF;
END;
/*
Result:

SELECT 'col1' AS my_col1, 'col2' AS my_col2 FROM DUAL
l_cur IS OPEN
*/
```